# Windows update errors 0x8007007b 0x80240017 volume licencing

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, volume-license

Recently we had to purchase 6 copies of Windows 10 Pro to update some Windows 7 computers to comply with Cyber Essentials.

When we did this, we looked hard for the cheapest copies we could find without buying volume licences.

However, the ones we found, although not advertised as volume licences, were actually volume licences.  We discovered this after purchasing 6 of them and installing them.

Everything worked fine for a while.

Then 6 different Windows 10 Pro computers that we have failed to update.  They give error codes 0x8007007b and 0x80240017, indicating that they were looking for a KMS (key management server).  These are OEM copies of Windows 10 Pro that came with the computers they are installed on.

I did try removing the product key (`slmgr /upk`), and rearming (`slmgr /rearm`) and then installing the updates while in the state of “waiting for activation” but when Windows restarted to do the install it must have somehow reinstalled the product key and reactivated itself because it was activated when it had finished booting and gave exactly the same error.

We have since purchased 5 and installed 4 genuine Windows 10 Pro Licences over the volume licences (`slmgr /ipk xxxxxxx`; `slmgr /ato`), but although it has eased my conscience somewhat, it has made no difference to the update problem we have.  Regardless, I hope to replace all 6 licences.  However, I also need to sort out the problem!

When initially installed the volume licence editions of windows self-identified as “VOLUME_MAK” channel.  After some time, they identified as “RETAIL” channel.  After installing a new licence, they identify as the expected channel.  This information was taken from the output of `slmgr /dli`, and is also how I discovered they were volume licences.

Despite the Windows update errors, none of the computers – OEM or volume licenced – have ever reported that they think they have pirated copies of Windows; they all report that they are permanently activated, whether or not they will update.

Comment: There really isn't a solution to your problem without being able to configure a KMS and actually activating the licenses you purchased.  However, if you purchase OEM licenses, that won't be possible.  When you install a VLK installation, there is a grace period, so you were activated by that installation must communicate with a KMS every 180 days.  There are also a minimum number of clients that must check otherwise other issues araise (but that isn't your particular problem).

Answer (score 0):

I have now tried a very basic solution which appears to have worked.  On one of the computers that would not update Windows I have reformatted drive C: (the system drive) and reinstalled the same version of Windows (10 Pro OEM).  It picked up the original product key from the BIOS and activated itself.  It also proceeded to install all the necessary updates.  I did this on 2020-03-23.  Being cautious I waited till today (2020-03-25), when it had also installed Windows 10 update KB4541335 before saying that it has worked!

Comment: I am still very curious about this and would love to know why it worked, and do I expect a random 2 of the 6 with problems to not work yet even though I try this method because I have only replaced 4 of the 6 volume licences so far?  Or will this method cause the 2 remaining volume licences to flag themselves as pirated?  Is there another method that is less time consuming?  Is there a way to tell if this method will work or not before investing so much time in it?  Or is it not a permanent fix, will the problem resurface later?